# specialization in type classes using ghc

Tags: haskell, rules, specialization, ghc, typeclass

How can I make the genOut/String fire?

```
module IOStream where

import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe

class Out a where
  out :: a → String

instance Show a ⇒ Out a where
  out = show

outString :: String → String
outString = id
{-# RULES "genOut/String" out = outString #-}

infixl 9 <<, ≪
(≪), (<<) :: Out a ⇒ IO Handle → a → IO Handle
(<<)= (≪)
h ≪ a = do
  s ← h
  hPutStr s $ out a
  return s

cout, cin, cerr :: IO Handle
cout = return stdout
cin  = return stdin
cerr = return stderr

endl :: String
endl = "\n"

--infixr 9 ∘ °
(∘) = (.)
(°) = flip (∘)
```

---

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import IOStream

foreign import ccall "pi.h f_" f_ :: IO Double

main :: IO Int
main = do
  --putStrLn . show =<< f_

--  ((≪ endl) . (cout ≪)) =<< f_ 
  (cout ≪) ° (≪ endl) =<< f_
  return 0
```

---

Compile and link:

```
cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.10.2
cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$ ghc -fglasgow-exts -O2 -ddump-simpl-stats -XUndecidableInstances -O2 iostream.hs main.hs pi_v2.o -o hsex2

==================== FloatOut stats: ====================
0 Lets floated to top level; 1 Lets floated elsewhere; from 3 Lambda groups



==================== FloatOut stats: ====================
0 Lets floated to top level; 0 Lets floated elsewhere; from 5 Lambda groups



==================== Grand total simplifier statistics ====================
Total ticks:     184

40 PreInlineUnconditionally
45 PostInlineUnconditionally
24 UnfoldingDone
8 LetFloatFromLet
4 EtaReduction
57 BetaReduction
6 KnownBranch
11 SimplifierDone



==================== FloatOut stats: ====================
0 Lets floated to top level; 0 Lets floated elsewhere; from 1 Lambda groups



==================== FloatOut stats: ====================
3 Lets floated to top level; 0 Lets floated elsewhere; from 1 Lambda groups



==================== Grand total simplifier statistics ====================
Total ticks:     218

42 PreInlineUnconditionally
57 PostInlineUnconditionally
33 UnfoldingDone
9 LetFloatFromLet
1 EtaReduction
66 BetaReduction
10 KnownBranch
12 SimplifierDone
```

---

Result:

```
cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$ ./hsex2
3.141592653589793"\n"cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$
```

---

Expected:

```
cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$ ./hsex2
3.141592653589793
cetin@unique:~/lab/c/linking/demo$
```

---

How can I make that rule fire?

Comment: My goodness, you're having too much fun with those Unicode characters, aren't you?  :)

Comment: Hehe this is nothing compared to some other little adventures I had with them ^_^" ... I love them *^o^*!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want [overlapping instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/OverlappingInstances), as you want to have an `instance Out String` which is different than `instance Show a => Out a` which overlaps it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
class Out a where out :: a -> String
instance Out String where out = id
instance (Show a) => Out a where out = show
```

The general recommendation is to avoid use of overlapping instances and undecidable instances unless **truly** necessary, as the changes to typechecking that they make are not portable and can cause other issues.

---

### Edit

Implementation-wise, think of dictionary for each instance of a class.  `<<` will be given the dictionary for the instance of `Out` that it is expected to use as a hidden parameter.  Since `out` is being looked up from there, there's no room for your `RULE` to fire.  If `out` weren't in a typeclass, and was being called from a non-polymorphic function, then I would expect the `RULE` to match, but as is, it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

`RULE`/`SPECIALIZE` are meant to be optimizations only, and your code should not change behavior if they do or do not fire.

It took me a while to realize what you were doing… you do realize that Haskell is not C++, right?  The ways in which polymorphism is utilized is quite different.